# Как сделать несколько режимов в приложении iOS на swift

Tags: ios, swift

Делаю приложение на `iOS` на `swift3`

В приложении 3 режима:

> 1. Анонимный юзер
> 2. Простой юзер
> 3. Компания

`RootVC` это `TabBar` как в `Instagram`.

У анонимного и простого юзера 5 элементов TabBar.

У Компании 4 элементов TabBar.

Как мне не закрывая приложение переключаться между ними?

Приложение без `storyboard`. Все делаю в коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишу тут подробнее может кому то поможет как я это сделал.

Приложение как я уже говорил основано на TabBarController

1. Режимы надо разделить на свои классы у меня до этого было все в 1 классе. Я разделил их на 3 класса.
2. Изначально задать root класс в AppDelegate

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

   window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
   window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

   UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white

   window?.rootViewController = AnonymUserTabBarController()

   return true
   }
   ```
3. Потом меняю его где захочу с анимацией.

   ```
   guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {
       return
   }

   guard let rootViewController = window.rootViewController else {
       return
   }

   let viewController = CompanyTabBarController()        
   viewController.view.frame = rootViewController.view.frame
   viewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()

   UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.6, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
       window.rootViewController = viewController
   }, completion: nil)
   ```